# pesquisar valor em objeto json e retornar posição no array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Há alguma maneira de pesquisar pelo sobrenome no objeto e retornar a posiçao no array principal?

Ex.: Pesquisando SOUZA retornar a posição do index no array e recuperar os mesmos dados para exibição.

```js
function filtrar(){
   var quadro=[
        {"numero_id":"2500","posto":"43","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"14","p_cidade":"Cruz Alta","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"4"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO1"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"SABINO"}],"salario":"5790,40","usuario":"Gerente","nivel":4,"dias":"457","status":"ativo"},
 {"numero_id":"2115","posto":"43","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"14","p_cidade":"Cruz Alta","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"4"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO2"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"LEE"}],"salario":"1321,80","usuario":"Colaborador 1","nivel":2,"dias":"391","status":"inativo"},
 {"numero_id":"1290","posto":"43","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"14","p_cidade":"Cruz Alta","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"4"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO3"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"SOUZA"}],"salario":"1321,80","usuario":"Colaborador 1","nivel":2,"dias":"391","status":"ativo"},
 {"numero_id":"708","posto":"10","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"1","p_cidade":"Caxias do Sul","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"7"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"NÃO URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO7"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"SANTOS"}],"salario":"5790,40","usuario":"Gerente","nivel":4,"dias":"856","status":"ativo"},
 {"numero_id":"240","posto":"21","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"12","p_cidade":"Sao Paulo","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"4"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO8"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"SILVA"}],"salario":"1321,80","usuario":"Colaborador 1","nivel":2,"dias":"391","status":"ativo"}
   ];
   var valorpesq = $("#pesq").val();
   var alvo = quadro;
   index = alvo.findIndex(x => x.numero_id==valorpesq);
   var alvo2 = quadro[index];
   var result = $(alvo2.sub_infos).each(function(key, value){
       var valorpesq = $("#pesq").val();
       $("#resultado").html("<br> Nome: "+  alvo2.sub_infos[0].valor + " " + value.valor +" <br> Salário: " + quadro[index].salario);
    
   });
   $("#resultado2").html("<br><b> Posição do index "+index+": </b> <br>"+ JSON.stringify(alvo2));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" id="pesq" value="1290">
   <button onclick="filtrar()">filtrar</button>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <div id="resultado"></div>
   <div id="resultado2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não é exatamente o que você já faz com o ID? qual é exatamente a sua dúvida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso é usar o `findIndex()` no array do `sub_infos` dentro da busca do `findIndex()` do array principal.

Exemplo:

```js
var quadro=[{"numero_id":"2500","posto":"43","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"14","p_cidade":"Cruz Alta","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"4"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO1"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"SABINO"}],"salario":"5790,40","usuario":"Gerente","nivel":4,"dias":"457","status":"ativo"},
 {"numero_id":"2115","posto":"43","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"14","p_cidade":"Cruz Alta","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"4"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO2"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"LEE"}],"salario":"1321,80","usuario":"Colaborador 1","nivel":2,"dias":"391","status":"inativo"},
 {"numero_id":"1290","posto":"43","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"14","p_cidade":"Cruz Alta","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"4"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO3"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"SOUZA"}],"salario":"1321,80","usuario":"Colaborador 1","nivel":2,"dias":"391","status":"ativo"},
 {"numero_id":"708","posto":"10","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"1","p_cidade":"Caxias do Sul","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"7"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"NÃO URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO7"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"SANTOS"}],"salario":"5790,40","usuario":"Gerente","nivel":4,"dias":"856","status":"ativo"},
 {"numero_id":"240","posto":"21","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"12","p_cidade":"Sao Paulo","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"4"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO8"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"SILVA"}],"salario":"1321,80","usuario":"Colaborador 1","nivel":2,"dias":"391","status":"ativo"}
];

function indicePorSobrenome(arr, sobrenome) {
  return arr.findIndex(function (v) {
    return v.sub_infos && v.sub_infos.findIndex(function (v2) {
      return (v2.tipo === "SOBRENOME" && v2.valor === sobrenome);
    }) >= 0;
  });
}

console.log(indicePorSobrenome(quadro, "SOUZA"));
console.log(indicePorSobrenome(quadro, "SABINO"));
console.log(indicePorSobrenome(quadro, "LEE"));
console.log(indicePorSobrenome(quadro, "STARK"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Usando `for...in` na array principal você consegue buscar dentro da subarray `sub_infos` a string buscada e retornar o valor da *index* quando o laço parar ao encontrar a ocorrência. Para ignorar o *case sensitive*, usei `.toLowerCase()` na string buscada e na string da array a buscar.

Declarei a variável `index` antes do laço `for`. Caso nada seja encontrado, ela será `undefined` e o `if` entrará na condição `else`.

> **Obs.:** Caso haja mais de uma entrada com o mesmo sobrenome, irá sempre retornar o primeiro encontrado. Como seu exemplo é apenas
>   retornar 1 índice, esta solução irá servir.

**Veja:**

```js
function filtrar(){
   var quadro=[
        {"numero_id":"2500","posto":"43","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"14","p_cidade":"Cruz Alta","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"4"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO1"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"SABINO"}],"salario":"5790,40","usuario":"Gerente","nivel":4,"dias":"457","status":"ativo"},
 {"numero_id":"2115","posto":"43","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"14","p_cidade":"Cruz Alta","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"4"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO2"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"LEE"}],"salario":"1321,80","usuario":"Colaborador 1","nivel":2,"dias":"391","status":"inativo"},
 {"numero_id":"1290","posto":"43","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"14","p_cidade":"Cruz Alta","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"4"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO3"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"SOUZA"}],"salario":"1321,80","usuario":"Colaborador 1","nivel":2,"dias":"391","status":"ativo"},
 {"numero_id":"708","posto":"10","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"1","p_cidade":"Caxias do Sul","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"7"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"NÃO URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO7"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"SANTOS"}],"salario":"5790,40","usuario":"Gerente","nivel":4,"dias":"856","status":"ativo"},
 {"numero_id":"240","posto":"21","posto_id":"-","cidade_id":"12","p_cidade":"Sao Paulo","empresa_tipo":"2","request":1,"servicos_prestados":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"4"}],"turno":"diurno","vencendo":"SIM","verificar":"URGENTE","descricao":"descricao ","sub_infos":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO8"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"SILVA"}],"salario":"1321,80","usuario":"Colaborador 1","nivel":2,"dias":"391","status":"ativo"}
   ];

   var valorpesq = $("#pesq").val().toLowerCase();
   var alvo = quadro;
   var index;
   for(var i in alvo){
      if(alvo[i].sub_infos[1].valor.toLowerCase() == valorpesq){
         index = i;
         break; // suspende o laço caso tenha encontrado uma ocorrência
      }
   }
   
   if(index){
      var alvo2 = quadro[index];
      var result = $(alvo2.sub_infos).each(function(key, value){
          var valorpesq = $("#pesq").val();
          $("#resultado").html("<br> Nome: "+  alvo2.sub_infos[0].valor + " " + value.valor +" <br> Salário: " + quadro[index].salario);
               
      });
      $("#resultado2").html("<br><b> Posição do index "+index+": </b> <br>"+ JSON.stringify(alvo2));
   }else{
      $("#resultado").html("Nada encontrado com "+ valorpesq);
      $("#resultado2").empty(); // esvazia a div
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pesq" value="SOUZA">
<button onclick="filtrar()">filtrar</button>
<hr>
<hr>
<div id="resultado"></div>
<div id="resultado2"></div>
```

Comment: por algum motivo quando uso na pratica há uma variação nos dados sub_infos, de:":[{"tipo":"NOME","valor":"FULANO3"},{"tipo":"SOBRENOME","valor":"SOUZA"}]

Comment: TRanquilo... explique que tipo de variações podem ocorrer que a gente faz o código.

Comment: Pelo teor da pergunta, a resposta resolve o problema... Se tem mais alguma coisa a mais, aí vc deveria ter explicado na pergunta inicialmente.

Comment: Explique a variação para que possamos adaptar o código.